# What to change 'localhost' with?

Tags: node.js

I just finished my Node app, which is working fine, but I'm not experienced about deployment.

```
exports.update_ibare = (req, res) =>{
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/ibare', { params : { id : req.query.id }})
    .then(function(response){
        res.render("update_ibare", { ibareler : response.data})
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.send(err);
    })}
```

What am I going to change localhost with, before I deploy this? I'm going to deploy to gcloud.

Comment: You've given nowhere near enough information for anyone to answer this, are you asking us to tell you (to _guess?_) what URL you're going to deploy to? I think the easiest solution, as I've set up [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture) is to use relative routes between the client and server - this means no CORS handling or configuring the client to find the server.

Comment: @alex-scott got what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method here would be to pull the URL from an environment variable from the host system as environment variables are normally easy to setup and allow your code to be as portable as possible, but this is only possible when compiling the code using a module bundler such as Webpack.
Some example code is below.

```
exports.update_ibare = (req, res) => {
  axios
    .get(`${process.env_API_URL}/api/ibare`, { params : { id : req.query.id }})
    .then(function(response){
        res.render("update_ibare", { ibareler : response.data})
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.send(err);
    })
}
```

In the event that you aren't using a bundler or compiler, I'd suggest that you start too, so you can replace strings like this with environment variables to make your code portable.

Comment: This appears to be a request _to_ the backend, though, _from_ the client (which wouldn't have access to the environment variables).

Comment: And note that baking in the env vars at build time, as e.g. Angular environments and Create React App's [use of Webpack](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) do, doesn't really make your code portable - you now have to do a separate build for every deployment target. I wrote about this here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html

Comment: You don't really have to do a build for each deployment target, just the backend that it's using in this case.

Comment: Also, depending on the chosen server, your code can still use environment variables, as Nuxt does with public runtime config. So, just because the code is client-side, it in no way means that environment variables can't be used.

Comment: That _is_ the deployment target. Based on the post there are _at least_ two targets, localhost and GCloud. In Nuxt's case I believe that's using server-side rendering, that's not the case with every SPA.

Comment: A deployment target IMO would be where you're deploying the web app too, bot the services it uses. They would be the API.

Comment: If this web app contacts multiple APIs, does that mean the the web app is built for multiple deployment targets simultaneously?

Comment: _"A deployment target IMO would be where you're deploying the web app too"_ - ...yes? Each deployment target would be a _collection_ of the services/APIs the client talks to, because they will likely _also_ have different environments (e.g. in a staging environment maybe the app talks to sandbox versions of the services, vs. the real live services in the production environment).